# How to shut down Apple TV (2G) remotly?

Tags: appletv, remote-control

Is there any way to shut down Apple TV (new, 2G, second generation) by remote controler?
I can do it by holding middle button on remote controller but only if the TV set is on. If I just listen to the internet radio without TV set on, I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, the "Sleep Now" menu entry for the AppleTV is in the lower right-hand corner of the menu system.

Here's how I do it:

1. Press the "menu" button several times, until you hear the different audio sound to indicate that you're at the home screen.
2. Press the "right" button several times, until you'd think that the cursor is over on the farthest right option.
3. Press the "down" button several times, until you'd think that the cursor is at the "Sleep Now" option.
4. Press the "middle" button.

I do this a lot when I am streaming music to the device; takes me about three seconds and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shutdown the Apple TV 2G as the powersupply does not support it.

But you can hold Play / Pause for 6 seconds on the remote, then it will go into standby. From this state it is safe to remove power from the unit.

If you have SSH you can issue the command **sudo shutdown -h now** to activate standby.